# Looking for an onEdit script that can be used to change the color of a google sheets cell when it is edited?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using google sheets to monitor a project that includes multiple users.  I would like to use an onEdit command to change a cell's color to yellow when the content is edited.  Below is the code that I am working with.  However, I am unable to get it to function.  Coding is still new to me, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
function onEdit1(e)
{
  var range=e.range;
  var column=range.getColumn();
  if(column>3 && column<27)
  {
    range.setBackground('#ffff00')'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e){
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName()!="Sheet1")return;
  if(e.range.columnStart>3 && e.range.columnStart<27) {
    e.range.setBackground('#ffff00');
  }
}
```

I also added a line to limit it to only one sheet.  You may wish to change the name of that sheet or even remove it entirely if you want it to run on your entire spreadsheet.

A lot of new programmers try to run these onEdit(e) functions from the script editor.  Unfortunately, that doesn't work because the e parameter is expecting to be populated by the event trigger.  Without the event object you'll normally get an error like Cannot read property range from undefined because e has not been populated by the event trigger.

I test them by making sure I'm editing the correct sheet and correct range and I use the e.source.toast() function to provide me with feed back sort of like the console.log() does.

If you want to learn more about the event object then try adding a Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)); to the first line after the function declaration. And then get it to run by editing the appropriate sheet in the appropriate way and go to view log to see the results.

Comment: I have run the code and have encountered the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code").  Please advise.

Comment: You cannot run this code from Script Editor. It must be run from a trigger so that it gets the event object  populated correctly